# Two ORDER BY / pick one by random

Tags: php, mysql

I have a comment section that's sorted by likes.

```
SELECT msg 
FROM msgs 
WHERE topic='$topic' 
ORDER BY likes_a ASC

SELECT msg 
FROM msgs 
WHERE topic='$topic' 
ORDER BY likes_b ASC
```

However, as I have 2 kinds of likes I want the comments to be sorted one way or the other (likes_a or likes_b) at random every time the page is refreshed or loaded. But I have no idea how to achieve this.

I'd go something like: `ORDER BY likes_a ASC OR ORDER BY likes_b ASC = AT RANDOM` but obviously this is not the correct coding.

Comment: union that queries and then order by rand subquery

Comment: the way I'd do it is retrieve both, then do the random on the front-end.  This also allows you to easily do something like provide a dropdown for the user to select which way they want them retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to randomly select a value, use that to select a column.

```
SELECT msg, IF(@rnd < 0.5, likes_a, likes_b) AS sort
FROM msgs
WHERE topic = '$topic'
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rnd := RAND()) AS r
ORDER BY sort ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to 'append' a new column to the table via the SQL statement and sort by it. The best thing for that would be a GUID(). In MySQL it should look like this:

```
SELECT msg FROM msgs WHERE topic='$topic' ORDER BY newid()
SELECT msg FROM msgs WHERE topic='$topic' ORDER BY newid()
```

Answer (score 1):

Transform what is random into a variable.

SELECT msg FROM msgs WHERE topic='$topic' ORDER BY '$order' ASC

PHP

```
$options = ['likes_a', 'likes_b'];
$rand = array_rand($options, 1);
$order = $options($rand);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tagged PHP I would imagine that this will fit the bill:

```
// Use PHP's rand() function to generate either a 0 or 1
// If rand() gives a 0 the use likes_a else use likes_b

$sql = "SELECT msg
          FROM msgs
         WHERE topic='$topic'
         ORDER BY likes_".(rand(0,1) === 0 ? 'a' : 'b')." ASC";
```